# Why cannot run an executable file with exec() or system() functions?

Tags: php, apache, exec, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run `notepad` on the server (`localhost` for now).

`exec()` and `system()` functions are working fine when for example write `ping 127.0.0.1`.

But this does not work (working fine if I write the command directly in the command prompt):

```
$command = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe";

$result = system($command);

print_r($result);
```

Using `Windows XP` with `xampp`. Probably I don't have permissions because the command is executed from some other account but I don't know how to check this.

Any advices?

**Edit:**

As [`bwoebi`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16037080/1333512) said, I have opened processes but they are opened from a different user (SYSTEM) and I can't see when the application is opened. So, I have to paraphrase my question: how to change the user which is used when executing commands from a PHP script?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to escape the backslashes in your command string if you're not using single quotes :

```
$command = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe";
```

Also note that if Apache is running as a Windows service, it does not have desktop interaction permission, so **it can't open a GUI**, try running the script directly with PHP on the command line.

**EDIT**

The user used to run command is the user that is running PHP. To change the user running PHP, you'll have to change the user running Apache, **if you want this user to have desktop interaction permission, you'll have to run Apache yourself and not as a service.**

Comment: Your problem seems to be elsewhere but note that you have to escape the backslashes somehow. Also try my last edit's suggestion.

Comment: thank you, I try to open gui by xampp and vertrigo, they are working, only wamp can not run gui(due to run as service). I try to compare the configuration between them, and no lucky. but your comment explains why my investigation is dead end.  my solution is run mysql through wamp, and use php -S 127.0.0.1:80 (php > 5.4)to run web server, then exec can run gui application. later I will find better solution.

Answer (score 0):

let the process a bit sleep after executing the shell command and search in the TaskManager for a Notepad... Then you'll see that this are two different users (and you don't see the other users Notepad)

Comment: You are absolutely right! Now I am seeing that I have opened processes with user `SYSTEM`. I will edit my question.

Comment: `sleep($interval);` in your PHP-script at the end. (in seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Note pad is a GUI program so requires the windows TTY to be active.

Ping is command line so can be ran by the system directly and piped results into the program calling it.

With out getting into too much detail of how os's work basically it can't be done on a windows machine (its possible on unix machines but more difficult.)

Comment: I don't know it exactly, but when I write on my OS X `shell_exec("open /Application/TextEdit.app");` it opens, only as the wrong user.

Comment: @bwoebi It should be opened as the user running PHP, which is probably the user running the web server, so it's not very surprising.

Comment: @zakinster exactly what I wanted to say with "the wrong user".

Comment: osx being *nix based :) you have apache running in userspace most likely run apache as a daemon then try it again :).  You can actually be quite amusing using X window manager (darwin uses a variant of I believe) where you can redirect output to different TTY's which don't have to be local they can also be remote x sessions.  Of course all of this is pointless since most unix servers do not have X installed and both unix and windows servers rarely have anyone seeing the output/desktop.  All of this is of course crazy as its a massive security hole hence the separation of application and OS.